# How to use Amazon Device Farm with GoCD

Tags: appium, go-cd, aws-device-farm

We are planning to config CI for our mobile apps (both Android and iOS). I've tried to use Device Farm with our Java and TestNG scrips and it works well. However, I have no idea how to use your device cloud with our current GoCD to implement  CI/CD for mobile development. I noticed Device Farm have plugin for Jenkins but not GoCD.
Could you guys please consult me in this case? Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Device Farm engineer here. We don't have any plans (as of mid-2017) to develop a GoCD plugin. However, the [service API is documented and publicly available](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) and you can use it and [the Jenkins implementation](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-jenkins-plugin) as a reference to build your own integration.